# Copying Drupal website and transfer to another hosting and domain

Tags: php, sql, drupal

How to copy the site on the CMS Drupal? At the moment, I just completed the export of the database, then made a copy of the site from the hosting. And uploaded to the new hosting, in the domain directory, the copied site, and through phpmyadmin imported the database. I got this error ...

> Error The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again
>   later. Error messagePDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied
>   for user 'rvsrru_c1035'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of
>   /home/aufhcrw3/public_html/includes/lock.inc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this [tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/upgrade-to-drupal-7/copying-your-live-site-to-a-test-site-command-line)

1. Copy project
2. Create user and add permission.  It's you can change on phpmyadmin

[image]

3. Change settings.php

   `$databases = array (
     'default' =>
     array (
       'default' =>
       array (
         'database' => 'yourdatabasename',
         'username' => 'databaseusername',
         'password' => 'databasepassword',
         'host' => 'localhost',
         'port' => '',
         'driver' => 'mysql',
         'prefix' => '',
       ),
     ),
   );`

Import DB. As I understand you  have already done :)

Comment: I don't have block - users. And i can't create new user.

Comment: Do you have block Privileges?

Comment: No. I have only: Structure, SQL, Search, Request by pattern, Export, Import, Operations, Procedures, Developments, Triggers, Designer.

Comment: okay, do you have login and pass for phpmyadmin? these are your data for username and password in settings.php

Comment: Thank you. I solved my problem. I'm create new user for DB in cpanel. And change setting in file - seting.php. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the settings.php file which is located in sites/default, and add the right database connection credentials. You'll also need to search and replace any references to the old URL to the new URL in your database, but that's not the problem you're facing right now and is best addressed by another question / google search

Have you read the documentation on this? [Migrating a site](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/backing-up-and-migrating-a-site/migrating-a-site)

Answer (score 2):

@Gariko, please change database credentials in settings.php file. Update database name, database user and password of new environment. **Check for host also.
After this clear cache by drush, via db tables or admin.**

Comment: This is true. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If who have this promblem. Reading please this is site - https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/backing-up-and-migrating-a-site/migrating-a-site
Next step. Create new user for DB in phpmyadmin or cpanel. And change setting in file - seting.php. See above!